# Why is the return false not working on a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm running a Javascript *Switch Statement* when clicking on any element in the body. 
So, when a match is found (in this case, I'm targeting a button class and returning false), the *break keyword* should stop the execution and ignore all the rest of the code. Instead, the *default code block* still runs when I click on the button. It triggers a console message that I've set in the *default code block* and it shouldn't.

Why is the **return false or break keyword** not working?

How can I stop the **default code block** from running when there is already a match?

(Open the console to see messages)
Here is an example [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9sj4hLz/1/)

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).on('click', function(event) {

  var e = $( this );
  var eClass = e.attr( 'class' );

  switch( eClass ){

      case 'btn-default':

             return false;

             break;

      default:

          var identifier = $( '.identifier' );

          if (!$(event.target).find( $( identifier ) ).length ) {

                console.log( 'Identical' );

          }            
       }


 });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col visible" data-id="el_1">
        Visible Content
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
           Click
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="identifier" id="el_1"></div>
```

Comment: Because the return false is in the case that isn't being ran. Also quite confused as to why you're trying to get an attribute value from the document.

Comment: I perfectly understand what your saying but the default code block should only run if there is no match found. The element you're confused about is that I'm actually using it as a target for another code.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Add console.logs or a debugger statement to confirm and include console output in question. The answer you selected working seems to confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put: "btn btn-default" will not match "btn-default". You either need to split/check the classes, or use something like jQuery's [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) on the element.

You should use an if statement (`eClass.split(/ +/).includes('btn-default')` will split all your classes by whitespace, and [`.includes`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) will search for any class that matches btn-default):

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  var e = $( event.target );
  var eClass = e.attr( 'class' ) || ''; //Default to empty string if the class doesn't have an attribute of class.
  
  if ( eClass.split(/ +/).includes('btn-default') ) {
    return false;
  }

  var identifier = $( '.identifier' );

  if (!$(event.target).find( $( identifier ) ).length ) {
    console.log( 'Identical' );
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col visible" data-id="el_1">
        Visible Content
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
           Click
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="identifier" id="el_1"></div>
```

Also: jQuery has a [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) you can use as well, to determine if a class exists on an element.

Comment: Hello FrankerZ, I get this error message - Cannot read property 'split' of undefined...

Comment: @jQueryster See my update. You want to use `event.target` instead of `this`.

Comment: It worked! You've just saved me more headaches. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The class for your button is "btn btn-default" but your switch case looks only for "btn-default", which does not match.

Comment: Hello Babak, the console still gets triggered. Open the console and check it

Comment: Good catch. $(this) is the whole document, not the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass`, to check if the element contains the class `btn-default`. You can also get rid of your switch statement to make the code easier to read.

```
if($(this).hasClass('btn-default')) {
    return false;
}
else {
    var identifier = $( '.identifier' );
    if (!$(event.target).find( $( identifier ) ).length ) {
        console.log( 'Identical' );

    }   
}
```

Comment: Hello Ryan, the console still gets triggered. Open the console and check it

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @Ryan McCullagh thanks for helping out, btw, I didn't down vote  your answer.

Comment: @KevinB Actually it is, it's the object that was clicked.

Comment: @RyanMcCullagh well, no, it was the element that the event was bound to. In this case, `document`

Comment: @KevinB either way My answer simplifies his code. He was using the exact same `this`